# Why is my code ain't working in hackerearth while running on visual studio? MOST FREQUENT ELEMENT IN AN ARRAY

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The code below is providing the right output in visual studio but in HackerEarth it showing error as **System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.** and in GFG complier **Unhandled Exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**
Sample input: 5 1 1 1 1 2 and output : 1. This question is asked in HackerEarth 1-D array.

```
using System;
namespace HK
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int element = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                int tempelement = arr[i];
                int tempcount = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j] == tempelement)
                        tempcount++;
                }
                if (tempcount > count)
                {
                    count = tempcount;
                    element = tempelement;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(element);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us, what the correct output is supposed to be given a specific input?

Comment: Sample Input
5
1 1 1 2 2
Sample Output
1

Comment: Can you post a link to the hackererath challenge/ question, too, please?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/golf/distinct-count-2/

Comment: _" Input:
First line of input contains N, number of integers.
**Second line will contains N spaces separated integers.**"_ - You are not following that. So, it works if you give it _your_ input. But not if input is given in the form specified on Hackerearth.

Comment: Thanks, it was the first time for me. I got it wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that this is the sort of low-level code you would rarely write in practice, now that we have things like LINQ. The entire calculation can be done as a one-liner. Of course challenges like these typically prohibit such solutions because you're not learning enough if you do that (or something) but leveraging increasing levels of abstraction to do more with fewer keystrokes is one of the hallmarks of effective programming.

Comment: What @JeroenMostert said + as this measures score by the length of your code, it encourages you to take one-character-variable names and other syntactical shortcuts, like nested shorthand-ifs, which further reduces the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code per se, but with your understanding of the question.

You will get 2 inputs. One saying how many numbers to expect, and one a a string with the actual numbers.

Now before I will post a possible solution, let me give you my personal oppinion, as to why I think this particular challenge or lession is flawed:

> Formula for calculating the score : (max_score) - (number of characters in your code/15.0)

This right here encourages you to write small and compact code, using as small as possible namespace, class and variables names, taking syntactical shortcuts whereever possible and ommitting any non-functional characters like ... comments.

While there still are use-cases where you are heavily memory constrained, I do not think this is something a beginner in programming should worry about in this day and age.

So here is an accepted (not a good) approach from HackerEarth. It is for you to decide, if this helps you learn the language.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace MostFrequentElement
{
    class Programm
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //we don't need the first input in our approach, so we discard it
            Console.ReadLine();

            //read the second line and split it
            var number = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')
                //group it by itself
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                //order descending, by how often a number occured
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                //then break the tie, as per Jeroens comment
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Key)
                .First();
            Console.WriteLine(number.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

And just to prove my point regarding scoring: If you remove all comments, whitespaces and almost all linebreaks, you end up with:

```
using System;using System.Linq;
namespace M{class P {static void Main(string[] a){Console.ReadLine();
var n=Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')
.GroupBy(x=>x)
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count())
.ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key)
.First();Console.WriteLine(n.Key);}}}
```

This will give you 16.x points, compared to the more readable first iteration, which would award you only 11.

Comment: Your solution will fail if the list is comprised of copies of one number. You can simply insert a `.ThenBy(x => x.Key).First()` to implement the logic that the smallest value should tie-break.

Comment: Further proof that that site is not suitable for education, then. The first thing you write is tests for edge cases...

Comment: Yeah, didn't think this though all the way. Only until HE accepted it. I'll edit it in later on. Good catch.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've updated the answer - but it had to be `ThenByDescending`, as `thenBy` would fail one of their test cases.

Comment: That's nice -- the problem statement clearly says "in case Frequency of two numbers is same print the smaller one", so aside from incomplete their verification is also wrong. I take back my earlier comment -- the site is very good for education in that you learn a lot about programming in practice, just not in the way intended. :P

Comment: As long as you're golfing for size: a namespace is not required, nor does `Main` need to take arguments, so `using System;using System.Linq;Console.ReadLine();Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').GroupBy(x=>x).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key).First().Key)` is probably as small as you can get (and you might get away with leaving out `using System` if the site has an automatic preamble, but I haven't tested this).

Comment: You need at least the using statements, or you'd need to write out the full type declaration including namespace.

Comment: Yes and in the above I've left out the class and `Main` entirely, I see, but that's not legal in the version of C# supported by their compiler. :) The `M` namespace can still be omitted, though. Although at this point this is better off at [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: `using System;using System.Linq;class P {static void Main(){Console.ReadLine();Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').GroupBy(x=>x).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key).First().Key);}}` That will give you 17.x points.